# Scrollview problem

Tags: android, scrollview

In an activity, I have list of buttons and a listview. For every category I have a button and on click of that it shows corresponding data.Here is my xml code.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_1"
 android:text="first"
/> 
 <Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_2"
 android:text="second"
/> 
     <Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_3"
 android:text="three"
/> 
<Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_4"
 android:text="four"
/> 
  <Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_5"
 android:text="five"
/> 
  <Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_6"
 android:text="six"
/> 
 <Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_7"
 android:text="seven"
/> 
 <Button  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/button_8"
 android:text="eight"
/> 
 <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:visibility="gone"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

In this activity, first buttons are visible. Then on click of button, all buttons will be invisible and only list view is there. Problem is If I am using scroll view, I can scroll button but only half of list view can be seen means I cannot scroll it. If I am not using scroll view, I can scroll the list view but not buttons. Can anybody please help me, where I am wrong?
Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do NOT put a ListView inside a ScrollView. ListView already handles 
scrolling, you're only going to run into trouble.
```

In you case you can keep all the `Button` in a `seperate xml layout` with scroll and `ListView` in a seperate layout and use the `addHeaderView` property of `ListView` and add the layout of button's.

`Example of addHeaderView in` [ListView](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to just put the buttons as a **listview header**. This way you can scroll everything without the need for a ScrollView.

**see [ListView.addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)**